# Writing a .txt file, without a extra line?

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io, streamwriter

```
Public Sub WriteTextFile(ByVal SourceToWrite As String, ByVal LocationToWrite As String)
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    IO.File.Delete(LocationToWrite)
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(LocationToWrite, True)
    file.WriteLine(SourceToWrite)
    file.Close()
End Sub
```

This is a module I made to write to a .txt file. Every time it adds a new line with null value. wouldn't really bother me but it adds but then something that only suppose to have like 3 lines in it ends up with 5000 over time, anyone know how to not add that extra line while writing file?

Comment: WoW... sometimes i need to read what i write before i hit post.

Comment: So your problem is solved, then? Voting to close (or just delete the question).

Comment: *wouldn't bother me but it adds up, something that only****

Comment: You can edit questions (as well as answers and comments)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
file.WriteLine(SourceToWrite)
```

The WriteLine() function appends a newline character to its output.  To avoid that, use:

```
file.Write(SourceToWrite)
```

Comment: ... One reason I don't like coming here. It can make me feel really stupid... that simple... :D well Thank you!